# How should I save statistics to a database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, statistics

I have currently made an irc bot for twitch. I want to save statistics to a database with data like, how many users joined the channel, how many new followers were gained and other stuff too. I am not sure how this is done correctly but the way I have done it now is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stats(year,month,day,hour,joinedChannel,TotalFollowers);
```

But I feel like this will be a wierd way to do it. My question basicly is if there is a smarter way for me to save statistics like shown above.

edit:
Hmm well it seems like i didnt supply all the information. Currently I have a table looking like this "CREATE TABLE users(id,points,timespent,follower,followed,wMessage);" I have a few features in my bot like, song request and a queue to join games. I would like to have stats so I can see how many used song requests this day and how many used the queue feature this day and how many followed the channel this day, where "this" would be any chosen day. Wouldn't I need a more complex table design for that? –

Comment: SQL has a `DATETIME` datatype that can be used to store year, month, day, hour, minute, etc. all in 1 field. I would definitely use that over having multiple fields for 1 date. Also, how are you adding followers - could you just have a table called `followers` which has their ID and datetime they joined - then you can query the table to see how many followers you have. Generally, it's not advised to store calculated values (TotalFollowers) in a table if you can avoid it, but I don't know what data you can access.

Comment: Oh yea I could for sure have that, totalFollowers is maybe wrongly named. What i mean here is totalFollowers on the date year, month, day and hour So if 5 people followed one hour i guess they would get their own row. I do have a table called users where I other stuff like how long they watched the stream and if they followed the stream. Guess I could log here when they followed and when they joined the channel here too ?

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you're collecting meta stats on an interval (once a day, once a week, etc.), in which case it's fine to keep that field. If you're simply asking if your table structure looks ok, the only change I would say is to combine all your date/time fields into one DATETIME field

Comment: What is `joinedChannel` ??

Comment: Joinedchannel would be how many people joined the channel at the year month day hour(or the DATETIME you suggested) also I provided some more information in the answer below in a comment

Answer (score 2):

Combine all of your date_time columns into one using something along the lines of GETDATE() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. With what you are keeping track of now. There isn't really a reason to split up into a more complex table design.

So something like this.

```html
CREATE TABLE stats
(
 joinTime DATETIME,
 joinedChannel nvarchar(100), --who joined the channel?
 totalFollowers int
)
```

Comment: Hmm well it seems like i didnt supply all the information. Currently I have a table looking like this "CREATE TABLE users(id,points,timespent,follower,followed,wMessage);" I have a few features in my bot like, song request and a queue to join games. I would like to have stats so I can see how many used song requests this day and how many used the queue feature this day and how many followed the channel this day, where "this" would be any chosen day. Wouldn't I need a more complex table design for that?

Comment: Ok, if you are already storing all this information in the "users" table, then please don't make a "stats" table. The proper way to gather this information isn't by putting it into a table, but rather just querying the "users" table i.e. `SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE song_request <> NULL`. Is there a specific reason you want to store all these stats in a new table instead of simply querying the "users" table when you want to see the stats? Edit: If you're querying "users" each night and want to have a log of values as they change each day, a "stats" table is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could put year, month, day, hour in the same field. And the joinedChannel would be in another table. Then create a foreign key relationship of joinedChannel to stats. The whole thing would become more dynamically. You could also put the date in different table. At least year, but not day and hour...